# To what class of functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ belong fisheye-distortions?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I would like to understand the fisheye effect for images from the "vector field"-point of view.

Suppose we are given a bounded connected set $B\subset[0,1]^2$ (pre-fisheye) and we distort this set via a homeomorphism say $\phi$, i.e. $\phi(B)\subset[0,1]^2$ (post-fisheye).

**My question:** How would we model this function $\phi$?

**My thoughts:** Say this distortion is circular (as in most pictures with this effect) and towards the boundary of $[0,1]^2$ points should get "cramped up". Meanwhile close to some centerpoint $c\in ]0,1[^2$ point should get spread apart. So I think modelling such a function should involve such a center point and a degree of "cramping" that increases towards the boundary. However, I do not know how to model it precisely. In Photoshop there most certainly is a function for this, hence modelling it shouldn't be too hard, but I am struggling....

**Follow Up Question:** Suppose more generally that we have not necessarily a circular distortion, but any type of distortion induced by some closed injective curve $r:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$. How do we model $\phi$ then? And what about negative fisheye-distortions?

thanks in advance for any help.